# Modify the text inside an Html.EditorFor MVC with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, editorformodel

I'm working on a web application in which I have an EditorFor field for a date as follows:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FECHA_RETIRO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
```

I have a jquery method that selects an element from a dropdown list and depending on the selection has to retrieve its date from the database. The method is:

```
 $("#SIGLA_CURSO").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $("#SIGLA_CURSO").val();
        $.post('@Url.Action("obtenerFechasCurso", "PRESTAMOes")', { idCurso: selectedValue }, function (listaDatos) {
        alert(listaDatos);
            // handle the server response here
            $("#FECHA_RETIRO").val(listaDatos[0]);
            $("#Fecha_Fin_Prestamo").val(listaDatos[1]);
        });
     });
```

The thing is I want the FECHA_RETIRO field to show the date that I retrieve from the database, however I can't get to modify it. If I try to show a date in a textbox it works, but it doesn't using the editorfor and I think that that is the field I need to modify.

Is it possible using jquery? Thank you.

Comment: The code you have show will work fine, but your `@class = "datepicker"` suggests your using a jquery datepicker plugin?

Comment: Then you need to include the relevant information. What plugin? (and why are you using `EditorFor()` if your using a plugin anyway?)

Comment: Use `textboxfor` with a `readonly` attribute that will surely fulfill your requirement

Comment: The datepicker i'm using is included like this on the layout page:                           <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  and frankly I can't say the reason for the EditorFor, but if I change it to a TextBoxFor I'm not sure if it will work

Comment: What your list returns? only date or anyother data too?